# ng-hide hiding all icons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-hide

I have a table and am using ng-repeat to fill in the rows.  Within one table cell i have a few font awesome icons.  One in particular is a delete icon.  I want to show or hide that icon based on its store id.  I have in the controller set a variable initially as false.  If i remove the else block then all the delete icons are hidden.  If I dont have the else block in then none of the delete icons are hidden

Controller

```
vm.myItem = false;
function scrollItems() {
    var items;
    if (vm.fetchCriteria != null) {
        inventoryDataService.getItemList(vm.Criteria).then(function (result) {
            vm.data = result.data;
            items = vm.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < vm.data.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].storeID > 0) {
                    vm.myItem = true;
                }
                else {
                    vm.myItem = false;
                }
                vm.items.push(items[i]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<td ng-bind="item.onHandQty" ng-model="quantity"></td>
<td>
    <a ng-click="vm.open(item)"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></i></a>
    <a ng-click="vm.removeItem(item)><i ng-hide="vm.myItem" class="fa fa-trash fa-2x link-icon"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link fa-2x link-icon"></i></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me, If I'm wrong, I've a list of data which is generated from server, and I want to show this data using `ng-repeat` and **delete icon** will be shown if **storeID > 0**, if I'm right, then you can use the following code:

**Controller**

```
function scrollItems() {
   if (vm.fetchCriteria != null) {
       inventoryDataService
           .getItemList(vm.Criteria)
           .then(function (result) {
              vm.data = result.data;
           });
   }
}
```

**html**

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.data track by $index">

     <td ng-bind="item.onHandQty" ng-model="quantity"></td>

     <td>
         <a ng-click="vm.open(item)"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></i></a>
         <a ng-click="vm.removeItem(item)"><i ng-show="item.storeID > 0" class="fa fa-trash fa-2x link-icon"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link fa-2x link-icon"></i></a>
    </td>

 </tr>
```

Comment: Your correct but that change still has all of the delete icons hidden so I think i have a problem else where

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without data.

But let's say you have 2 items with the ids :

1. -1
2. 3

Without the "else" :

1. the first item return true for `items[i].storeID > 0`, so `vm.myItem = true`
2. the second item return false for `items[i].storeID > 0`, so `vm.myItem` stay `true`

At the end : `vm.myItem` value is `true` and all the icons will be hidden

With the "esle" :

1. the first item return true for `items[i].storeID > 0`, so `vm.myItem = true`
2. the second item return false for `items[i].storeID > 0`, so `vm.myItem = false`

At the end : `vm.myItem` value is `false`, and all icons are visible